# Define True, if not defined, causes syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have found the following construct today in someone elses code:

```
try: True, False
except NameError: True = 1==1; False = 1==0
```

As I understand this, it defines `True` and `False` if they are not defined already. So if they are defined it shouldn't throw the `NameError`-Exception, right?

I have tryed this for myself in a shell and it shows me `SyntaxError: can't assign to keyword`

My question is why does it even shot the syntax error if True and False are defined? If True and False are available on my system, shouldn't it just go past the exception handling and not show a syntax error?

Comment: Those lines make code compatible with pre-python 2.3 versions. (See [PEP 285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/)). But *nobody* uses python<2.3 and even python<2.5 is *really* rare. Currently you'd better try to make code portable in python2.7/3+

Comment: http://2ndscale.com/rtomayko/2003/TrueFalseInOldPython

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This code is written for Python 2.x and won't work on Python 3.x (in which `True` and `False` are true keywords).

Since `True` and `False` are keywords in Python 3, you'll get a `SyntaxError` which you cannot catch.

This code exists because of very old versions of Python. In Python 2.2 (released in 2001!), `True` and `False` did not exist as predefined names, so this code would provide compatible definitions so that later code could simply use `True` and `False`.

When converting your Python 2.x code to Python 3.x, remove these lines; they are historical and have no use in Python 3.x. If you see these lines in someone else's code, they are a sure sign that the program was not written or ported for Python 3.

Comment: “they are a sure sign that the program was not written or ported for Python 3” – or any Python version of this age… xD

Comment: What did they use instead? `int`s for boolean logic?

Comment: Yes indeed, they used 1 and 0. Note that `True` and `False` were added as constants in Python 2.2.1, but they were defined simply as `1` and `0` respectively. The actual `bool` type was only added in Python 2.3, via [PEP 285](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-bool.html).

Comment: (And to this date, `bool` is still a subtype of `int`)

Answer (score 9):

`SyntaxError` shows up during the byte-compilation stage, before the code is ever run -- so you can't get around it with `try`/`except`.

Answer (score 3):

The boolean type was introduced in Python 2.3: https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-bool.html

So that piece of code was for old version of Python, e.g. 2.3+ to support very old version of Python (i.e. prior to 2.3)