# NameError: True when using boolean values in jython on wsadmin cli utility

Tags: python, websphere, jython, wsadmin

Writing a jython script for wsadmin, it doesn't seem possible to use boolean values as this simple example shows.

app-stop.py:

```
isTrue = True
print isTrue
```

Call:

```
wsadmin.bat -lang jython -username user -password pw -f D:\app-stop.py
```

Result:

> D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on
>   node OurCellManager using SOAP connector;  The type of process is:
>   DeploymentManager WASX7017E: Exception received while running file
>   "D:\app-stop.py"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException:
>   exception from Jython: Traceback (innermost last):   File "",
>   line 1, in ? NameError: True

It doesn't matter if I'm writing `True` (which should be valid python) or `true`. The only way it works is `isTrue = 1`. But why is it not possible to use valid python code in jython on wsadmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jython in 8.5.5 and earlier is jython 2.1 which implements the language as it was in python 2.1. These constants were not in Python until 2.3.

jython was upgraded in 9.0.  This doc describes updating it locally in 8.5.5, but it's surprisingly involved:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1207_vansickel/1207_vansickel.html

Comment: "popular" WAS scripting library wsadminlib.py sets these constants up as well.

Comment: Found this answear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042827/define-true-if-not-defined-causes-syntax-error
Terrifying that IBM uses so extremly old software! Thanks for your reply.